# C type casts and addition precedence

Tags: c, syntax, c99

What's the precedence in the next expression?

```
item = (char*)heap + offset;
```

Is it `(char*)(heap + offset)` or `((char*)heap) + offset`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Cast [trumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) binary addition according to the precedence table.

[image: Precedence Table]

Answer (score 8):

It's `((char *)heap) + offset`. Casts have much higher precedence than addition.

Comment: This is quite correct, but if it's really unclear to the coder, then I'd recommend actually using the parentheses as shown here.

Comment: The problem rises when the original author coder doesn't have precedence order doubts in the case, but another maintenance coder has.

Answer (score 2):

```
((char*)heap) + offset
```