# Attempting to understand pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *c = "hello";
const char *cp = (unsigned char*)&c;
const char *cpp = (unsigned char*)&cp;



int main (){

        printf("PTR    c      %p \n",c);
        printf("PTR    cp     %p \n",cp);
        printf("PTR    cpp    %p \n",cpp);

        printf("\n\n");

        printf("CONTENTS cp   0x%x \n",*(unsigned int*)cp);
        printf("CONTENTS cpp  0x%x \n",*(unsigned int*)cpp);

        printf(" \n\n Demonstrating pointer arithmetic. \n\n");

        printf("PTR     c     %p \n ",c);
        printf("PTR    (c+1)  %p \n ",(c+1));


        printf("PTR     c     %p \n ",(unsigned int*)c);
        printf("PTR    (c+1)  %p \n ",(unsigned int*)(c+1));


        printf("PTR     c     %p \n ",(unsigned long*)c);
        printf("PTR    (c+1)  %p \n ",(unsigned long*)(c+1));

        return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is given below

```
PTR    c      0x4007a0 
PTR    cp     0x601028 
PTR    cpp    0x601030 


CONTENTS cp   0x4007a0 
CONTENTS cpp  0x601028 


Demonstrating pointer arithmetic. 

 PTR     c     0x4007a0 
 PTR    (c+1)  0x4007a1 
 PTR     c     0x4007a0 
 PTR    (c+1)  0x4007a1 
 PTR     c     0x4007a0 
 PTR    (c+1)  0x4007a1
```

If you look at the portion Demonstrating pointer arithmetic,I would expect the following results

1) The first two lines print 'char pointers' one address apart,hence the difference should be '1'  - which is what we are getting

2) The next two lines print 'int pointers' one address apart,hence the difference should be '4' - WHAT WENT WRONG??

3) The next two lines print 'long pointers' one address apart,hence the difference should be '4/8' - WHAT WENT WRONG??

Comment: When you do `&c` you get a pointer to `c`, so `&c` is a pointer to a pointer to `const char`.

Comment: I think you're incrementing before casting

Comment: This code is absolutely insane.  `const char *cpp = (unsigned char*)&cp;` makes _no sense at all_.

Comment: @Mooing Duck - why not?

Comment: Taking a `const char*`, taking the address of that (a `const char**`), explicitly casting that to a `unsigned char*` (which is dangerous and pointless), and then implicitly casting that to a `const char*` (equally dangerous and pointless).  It looks like what you wanted was `const char** cpp = &cp;`  Tip: If you have type casts in C++, your code is probably wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incrementing the values before casting them to the wanted pointer

To interpret 'c' as another pointer you should rather do

```
printf("PTR    (c+1)  %p \n ",(unsigned int*)c+1);
```

otherwise the parenthesis will give priority to the increment **before** the casting.

Without those parenthesis, casting has higher precedence than addition, like in the following

```
item = (char*)heap + offset;
```

that is equivalent to

```
item = ((char *)heap) + offset
```

Reference: precedence table [C type casts and addition precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3354446/1938163)

Comment: Which one is question #2? By fixing the casts the code should work (for what I suppose the user wants)

Comment: you can edit my post if you want, but I suppose that by fixing the cast pointers the procedure is the same for #2 and #3

Comment: Oh my, I 100% misinterpreted what he was saying.  My appologies, deleting my comments.

Comment: No problem, glad we straightened that out

Answer (score 0):

You should cast var to correct pointer before add them const value. Also i suggest cast type to unsingned long long to determine 64bit width:

```
    printf("PTR     c     %p \n ",c);
    printf("PTR    (c+1)  %p \n ",(c+1));


    printf("PTR     c     %p \n ",(unsigned int*)c);
    printf("PTR    (c+1)  %p \n ",((unsigned int*)c+1));


    printf("PTR     c     %p \n ",(unsigned long long*)c);
    printf("PTR    (c+1)  %p \n ",((unsigned long long*)c+1));
```

and the result is:

```
PTR     c     0x80485f0
 PTR    (c+1)  0x80485f1
 PTR     c     0x80485f0
 PTR    (c+1)  0x80485f4
 PTR     c     0x80485f0
 PTR    (c+1)  0x80485f8
```