# old-style simple cast precedence in c++

Tags: c++, casting, operator-precedence, static-cast

I have some old-style casting in some c++ code which I would like to convert to new-style. I had a look to precedence and associativity operators [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), but I failed to understand it.

```
( double ) myValueA() / myValueB()
```

is equivalent to

```
static_cast<double>( myValueA() ) / myValueB()
```

or to

```
static_cast<double>( myValueA() / myValueB() )
```

I suppose the answer will the same for other numerical operators (*/+-)

Comment: See [operator precendence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Casting has one of the highest precedent, higher than division and other arithmetic operations.

Comment: sorry, will reformulate

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux can you detail?

Comment: [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) resolves to a series of cast *as needed*. If `myValueA()` returns a value for which `static_cast<double>` would be sufficient, it's correct to view the `(double)` as one. It would only be a `reinterpret_cast` if the cast wasn't possible with `static_cast`. Also note that explicit type conversion can remove `const` which neither `reinterpret_cast` nor `static_cast` can do. So some explicit type conversions may also require a `const_cast` as part of the series.

Comment: Also note that _function call_ operator has higher precedence than _C-style cast_ operator. (BTW, its kind-of misleading that we say "higher precedence", but in the table referenced by @FrançoisAndrieux, the precedence has actually lower number).

Comment: Same question (for plain C): https://stackoverflow.com/q/3354446/94687

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In

```
( double ) myValueA() / myValueB()
```

`( double )` is a c-style cast.  If we look at the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) we will see that it has a higher precedence than the arithmetic operators so

```
( double ) myValueA() / myValueB()
```

is the same as

```
static_cast<double>(myValueA()) / myValueB()
```

Answer (score 7):

The cast has higher precendence, so it is equivalent to

```
static_cast<double>(myValueA()) / myValueB()
```