# Question about typecast behavior in arithmetic

Tags: c++, casting

I have the following code. My main question lies in line 5.

```
int x1 = extRes1.at(1).toInt();   //A fairly large int value. This is from Qt, where extRes is a QStringList. the key is, the function returns an int value.
int x2 = extRes2.at(1).toInt();
int y1 = extRes1.at(2).toInt();
int y2 = extRes2.at(2).toInt();
double c = (double)(y2*x1-y1*x2)/(x1-x2);   //Typecasting, as I want this arithmetic to return a floating point properly.
```

My question is, what is the exact behavior of the typecasting on line 5?
Based on [what I've found on the topic so far,](https://cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/) I believe that the result of Line 5 RHS `(y2  *x1-y1 * x2)/(x1-x2)` is represented by a `double`. But does typecasting work by turning all individual elements (such as `y2`, `x1`) in the arithmetic into the type (in this case `double`)? Or does it work by only converting the result of the final solution?

I am aware that on a technical level, my issue can be solved by converting the preexisting `int`s to `double`s. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Only the result of `(y2*x1-y1*x2)` which is an `int` is converted to `double`. Then this `double` is divided by `(x1-x2)` using floating-point division, yielding the `double` result.

Comment: Thank you. Could you put this in an answer?

Comment: Dupe: [old-style simple cast precedence in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410646/old-style-simple-cast-precedence-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the result of `(y2*x1-y1*x2)` *(which is an `int`)* is converted to `double`.

This is due to the **precedence of the casting operator**:
As you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), casting is priority over all "normal" artihmetic operations like multiplication and division.

Then this `double` is divided by the result of `(x1-x2)` *(an `int` promoted to `double` for the division)* using **floating-point division**, yielding the `double` result assigned to `c`.