# C Typecast struct and addition precedence

Tags: c

Is it correct interpretation of operator precedence that the following:

```
(uint8_t*)myData->buffer + bufferoffset
```

is the same as:

```
((uint8_t*)myData->buffer) + bufferoffset
```

But the parenthesis make intention more explicit?

Checking my understanding after looking at the following post:
[C type casts and addition precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354446/c-type-casts-and-addition-precedence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precedence is `->` over `()` (cast) over `+`. So yeah your two examples are equivalent.

But adding a parenthesis doesn't really improve anything IMO. `(uint8_t*)(myData->buffer)` might perhaps have improved readability.

Comment: Yeah I prefer the second one especially if the `->` chain is longer